# Why does FlatList's renderItem prop return inconsistent data from array?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

Goal: Use react-native's FlatList to render a list of touchable image's that when pressed, display a Modal of that respective image.

List.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    View,
    Text,
    Image,
    StyleSheet,
    Modal,
    FlatList,
    Dimensions,
    TouchableOpacity,
    TouchableWithoutFeedback
} from 'react-native';
const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const List = (props) => {
    const [ visible, setVisible ] = useState(false);
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <FlatList
                data={props.data}
                numColumns={2}
                renderItem={({ item, index }) => {
                    return (
                        <View>
                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setVisible(true)} style={styles.itemContainer}>
                                <Image style={styles.img} resizeMode={'contain'} source={item.img} />
                                <View style={styles.details}>
                                    <Text style={{ color: 'white', fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.name}</Text>
                                    <Text style={{ color: 'white' }}>{item.date}</Text>
                                </View>
                            </TouchableOpacity>
                            <Modal
                                animationType="fade"
                                transparent={false}
                                visible={visible}
                                presentationStyle={'overFullScreen'}
                            >
                                <View style={styles.modalContainer}>
                                    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => setVisible(false)}>
                                        <Image resizeMode={'contain'} style={styles.modalImg} source={item.img} />
                                    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
                                </View>
                            </Modal>
                        </View>
                    );
                }}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    img: {
        height: width * 0.65,
        width: width * 0.45
    },
    modalImg: {
        left: width * 0.12,
        top: height * 0.2
    },
    modalContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(69, 74, 102, .7)'
    },
    details: {
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(137,137,137, 0.75)',
        borderRadius: 10,
        height: width * 0.125,
        width: width * 0.4,
        left: '4%',
        top: '75%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});

export default List;
```

Implementation:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Dimensions, SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import Component from './Component';

const { width } = Dimensions.get('window');

const testArr = [
    { name: 'Josh Gordon', date: 'November 7, 2019', img: require('./src/assets/img/josh.png') },
    { name: 'Kylie Jenner', date: 'December 21 2019', img: require('./src/assets/img/kylie.png') },
    { name: 'Logic', date: 'December 15, 2019', img: require('./src/assets/img/logic.png') }
];

const App = () => {
    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={styles.screen}>
            <Component data={testArr} />
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#E6E6E6'
    }
});

export default App;
```

Problem: The initial FlatList renders with all three different images, but when *any* of the image buttons are pressed, the model is displayed with *only* the last image from the data array, even though the same `item.img` variable is used... Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have as many modals as there are items in the list, but only one `visible` variable which all modals use. When you click any item, `visible` becomes true for all modals and they are all rendered at once so you only see one of them.

Don't put modals inside the FlatList renderItem. Modal should always be rendered in the dom (but not always `visible`). Make only one modal, and store related information (modal visibility and which item to display inside modal) in the state. Then change it in onPress of your TouchableOpacity

Comment: When I try to save `item.img` (what I thought would be the file path as a string) to state and then try to render that image in the modal, nothing happens. then I find that `item.img` is just a number. somehow the path changes to a number so I cant use what I saved to state as the source for the image In the modal... any ideas?

Comment: after you `require()` some resource, in runtime the required path doesn't exist. It only exists during build time on your computer. Images are packaged into application and are referenced by resource id (the number you are talking about). So if you require something and print what you have, you will always end up with numbers. Don't bother storing this number in state, instead, store identifier for entry in your array, for example, name of the person you show modal for, or their index in the array. Then you will be able to get image by that name or index from your `testArr`

Comment: accessing the img in `testArr` from props results in a number. moving the modal, and onpress function to the parent component to access the `testArr` directly also results in a number

Comment: How do I display the image then

Comment: like always, you feed the result of `require` to `source` prop of `Image`

Comment: how am I supposed to do that dynamically when array result is a number...

Comment: I explained it in my first comment to this answer